# WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0xffffffff

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Unable to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in WSL 2. I have enabled all the required things for WSl.
It is resulting following error.
[image: Error message]

Comment: what is your version of windows and what guide did you follow?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Please try the following:

1. Go to System Tools => Resource Monitor GUI for windows
2. Check which service is using port **53**,
3. Once you identify it, kill the process as follows: `taskkill /f /pid [PID]`.
4. Go to `Users/[youruser]/AppData/Local/Packages/` and look for a folder called `CanonicalGroupLimitedUbuntu...` then right click on it, go to `Properties => Advanced Options` and disable compression for the folder, then click accept and also apply this change for subfolders.

**[Note]** Windows uses Compression for the installation folders so is not possible to run it.

Once this is done, try to run your installation and should be working.

Hope it helps. Regards

Comment: For me the part of the answer that solved the problem was killing the processes listening on port 53.

Comment: Is there a way to change the port needed by WSL2? We are forced to run security software that unfortunately uses that port and as of right now that cannot be changed. This did work for me when I temporarily disabled the security service but once it is back on WSL2 stopped working.

Comment: There's no service is using port 53 and I still receive this error.

Comment: Check the 53 port like this: start resmon.exe, go to Network tab, Listening Ports expander, order by port number.. If you kill the process and it starts again on the same port, it is probably a service. Go to services.exe, find it, disable and stop it.

Comment: I am always curious how people know these specific details about such a random error. You saved my day! Almost gave up using wsl 2.

Comment: @RonaldT Glad to hear it was useful ;-). Is always good to give back to the dev community and save other people's time.

Comment: @Voj https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4364#issuecomment-520533800 This might help. It worked for me.

Comment: On my machine it was the **Acrylic DNS Proxy** which blocked the port `53`.

Comment: How can I do it on windows 11? Cause there is no address like "`Users/[youruser]/AppData/Local/Packages/`" in.

Comment: Only clearing/killing 53 port worked for me, didn't have to do anything else.

Comment: Alternative to watch the ports: **TCPView** for Windows - Sysinternals. You can also kill the process from there.

Comment: it works for me

Comment: thx goes to @chviLadislav i found the port 53 was used by Acrylic... exe this blocked my Docker Desktop to get running, after killing the service, Docker was starting :)

Comment: I guess the poster tried to reinstall their distro, which in turn gives another generic, nonsensical error message. Searching for that gives you the most common error of port 53 being in use. The people at Docker & Microsoft really need to work on their logging as it's utterly useless in most cases.

Comment: Same here, having  Acrylic DNS preventing WSL to start. I disabled it, started WSL and enabled Acrylic DNS again and works.

Answer (score 20):

Open **PowerShell** as **Administrator** and run this command to set WSL back to version **1**.

```
PS C:\> wsl --set-default-version 1
```

If you have run the kernel update as of today before installing Ubuntu or Kali you will encounter this issue. This is the only way I have found to work around the issue. You can switch it back to WSL 2 after installing OS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This save the date! After switch to v1, install ubuntu, then switch back to v2 = work

Comment: After trying everything it finally worked thanks a lot, I couldn't run docker

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was a service was using port 53 and this was in turn stopping WSL/Docker from launching. It's just a shame that this issue isn't reflected in the error message at all. One more thing for people in the same situation to try.

Answer (score 0):

The error is occuring up to today. So I faced it as well.
After checking out the advices from the other answers I've just come up with simply `wsl --update` to upgrade the WSL2 version and after rebooting the failure was gone.

Answer (score -1):

**First**: The following hardware prerequisites are required to successfully run WSL 2 on Windows 10 or Windows 11:

1. 64-bit processor with Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)
2. 4GB system RAM
3. BIOS-level hardware virtualization support must be enabled in the BIOS settings. For more information,see [Virtualization](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/topics/)
4. Download and install the Linux kernel update package.[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package)

**Second**: Install WSL command with Windows PowerShell(Admin):

```
wsl --install
```

This command will enable the required optional components, download the latest Linux kernel, set WSL 2 as your default, and install a Linux distribution for you (Ubuntu by default, see below to change this).
The first time you launch a newly installed Linux distribution, a console window will open and you'll be asked to wait for files to de-compress and be stored on your machine. All future launches should take less than a second.
** Note**
The above command only works if WSL is not installed at all, if you run `wsl --install` and see the WSL help text, please try running `wsl --list --online` to see a list of available distros and run `wsl --install -d <DistroName>` to install a distro.

**If you still get the error**:

5. Open PowerShell as Administrator and run `wsl --install -d Ubuntu` to set WSL back to version 1